# spf blocked- can't send emails to people who uses gmail

Tags: email-server, spf

I use 1and1 Ionos for my email server  - I can't send emails to people who use google gmail

```
spf record v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all
```

I am not sure what I can do - I updated spf 2x

Need help here

```
 SMTP error from remote server for TEXT command, host: gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (142.251.4.27) reason: 
550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [bhbfunding.com] has an SPF record with a hard
550-5.7.26 fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF checks with the ip:
550-5.7.26 [74.208.4.194]. To best protect our users from spam and phishin g,
550-5.7.26 the message has been blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication fo r more
550 5.7.26 information. x10-20020a056902102a00b0066cc0f73bbasi6170373ybt.4
86 - gsmtp
```

Comment: I don't see your SPF record. `dig txt bhbfunding.com` shows `v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all` instead.

Comment: I used v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all 2 days ago and nothing happen same issue and then IONOs changed it to v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all

Comment: Should I change it back ?

Comment: You should change it to correctly reflect the servers the domain permits to send email on its behalf. I don't know which set is correct. Whose infrastructure do you use to send emails?

Comment: Your DNS records says that it's `v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all`. Are you sure you're changing it in the correct place?

Comment: yes - it was changed yesterday. @vidarlo

Comment: We use exchange the host is 1and1/IONOS @ceejayoz

Comment: @VictorCastillo That could mean the record didnt propaged yet, or where you changed it are slow to start the propagation.

Comment: I changed is back to v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all - how long will it take so our emails wont be blocked from google ?

Comment: If you use 1and1's email servers, that SPF is wrong. `secureserver.net` is GoDaddy's.

Comment: @yagmoth555 unlikely if he changed yesterday; TTL is 3600. I also tried asking NS records directly; same reply. My conclusion is that Victor has in fact not changed anything, and thus probably is looking at the wrong place.

Comment: @vidarlo My guess: OP's using 1&1 for hosting, GoDaddy for domain. They're making DNS changes at 1&1, but the domain's still pointed at GoDaddy's nameservers.

Comment: I tried dealing with IONOS - I am not looking at the wrong place.  the domain is with godaddy but my email server is with IONOS.  all I know my emails is not reaching my customers who uses gmail - We don't do mass marketing at all so no reason our emails should be flagged as phishing. what can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you all - you guys helped. you are right the wrong place - Godaddy dns to match IONOS - both has the same record -  v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all is the corrected one

Answer (score 3):

Google's error indicates your email was sent with the IP `74.208.4.194`. A quick Whois indicates that's a 1&1 email server.

`_spf.perfora.net` appears to include this IP in its range, so this record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all
```

would be correct. However, your domain *currently* has this SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all
```

which is GoDaddy's SPF record. That's why Google rejected the email.

Use the correct SPF record. If you send from both 1&1 *and* GoDaddy, you may need to combine the two. Make sure you're changing the records in the right place; bhbfunding.com is currently set to use GoDaddy's nameservers, so that's where you need to change the SPF.

Comment: okay thank you - I added the spf1 v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all - on godaddy dns manage settings

Comment: @VictorCastillo I see them now. Try sending a new email. If you still get an error, be aware that Google may have cached your record for an hour or two.